# Getting Error Loading javai.dll in VuGen of HP Load Runner

Tags: java, dll, jvm, loadrunner

When I'm trying to compile a simple script in HP load runner's VuGen.
It is failing to start the JVM with following error:
`Java VM Internal Error: Getting Error Loading javai.dll`

I'm using

- HP LoadRunner version 12.5
- Java version: 1.8.0
- JAVA_HOME and PATH variables are properly set - jvm found
- OS: Windows Server 2012r2 (64bit) running on a VM

I'm able to compile and run the normal java programs on the same machine.

What is this javai.dll? and Why is the JVM trying to load it when it is being triggered from HP Load Runner?
There are not more options to configure in Load Runner to manage this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8 is not supported by LoadRunner 12.50. Please consider upgrading to the version 12.53. You can also use [the Product Availability Matrices](https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM00828655) to check if some technology is supported by a particular LoadRunner version.

Comment: I offer a standing ovation to this post

Comment: Thanks for the useful info and link... The reason for posting is that we've actually been trying with java 1.8.0 and 1.7.9 (32bit ad 64bit) but get a mixture of errors. With the 1.7 jvm we get the same problem but complaining about `jvm.dll`.

Comment: Thanks for the ovation(!) but the reason for requesting is to check other's with similar experience. Note that this product matrix in the link above requires permissions to see (not just an HP login). Note also that there is a post on the LR forums indiciating that there is a specific 1.8 problem but the answer to it is also hidden behind needing more permissions. To be honest, HPs forums are a dog's dinner, Thankfully it's poss to obtain the product matrix through google but there are still questions... Perhaps an upgrade to 12.53 is in order to overcome java issues.

Comment: @wmorrison365, the link I've provided requires an HP Passport account, the one used to access the community forum. As for the `jvm.dll` error message with Java 7, this might be something different.

Comment: Thanks @tserg42. I do have a passport account but can't seem to see this link due to a concise "You don't have permission" message. Nevertheless, I have a version of the 12.50 product matrix confirming what you said (for some reason we'd referred to 12.53 version originally which didn't help). I/we'll vote/accept when we've played some more, possibly rolling back to an even earlier jvm, though upgrading may just end the pain. Thanks again...

Comment: @James Pulley I never seen crappy product like Load Runner. 12.50 to 12.53, such a big change doesn't deserve version upgrade delta of 0.03. And if from HP's point of view its a minor patch (0.03) then where the hell is the upgrade mechanism. HP support wants me to do full installation. It's not just this problem but this Load Runner is full of shit. If my organization permits I would never use this crap and would prefer to use some cleaner, better tool. IMO, it doesn't have a long life..

Comment: OK.  Clearly you never saw version 6.0.  Consultants would carry 5.02 in their briefcases so they could get real work done.   I recommend you take your issues up with HP.  Nothing so inspires action like a threat to stop using and stop paying for support.

Comment: To round off our findings on this issue, we remained on LR 12.50 and using java 1.7. I'll actually provide the details of how to get this working in an answer (as it's really rather convoluted and not at all intuitive), which might explain the mild consternation that can be deduced in Akshay's response above :-) - Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're using the 32bit version of JDK