# Can't run JavaVuser script in LoadRunner

Tags: java, java-7, performance-testing, loadrunner, java-home

[Here is very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006878/getting-error-loading-javai-dll-in-vugen-of-hp-load-runner) which doesn't help much.
I'm trying to run JavaVuser script and getting the next error:

```
Notify: Found jdk version: 1.7.0.   [MsgId: MMSG-22986]

... logs out my classpath & Path vars ...

Notify: VM Params: .    [MsgId: MMSG-22986]
Java VM internal error:Error Loading jvm.dll.
.   [MsgId: MERR-22995]
```

JAVA_HOME is set and java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin is added to path

**java version** "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
javac 1.7.0_80

**LoadRunner** version: 12.53 build 1203

**Windows** 10 x64

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a blank virtual user, or one with just an lr.message() present.  If this does not work then you have an environmental issue to address.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. Completely unmodified, with blank default functions (init, action ...)